# How to get the original TCP connection hostname in Python Twisted?

Tags: python, tcp, twisted

With Twisted's TCP mechanisms, when a protocol is created, the only information about the peer is its IP address and port. How can I retrieve the original hostname that I tried to connect with?

```
reactor.connectTCP('somehost.com', 80, MyFactory)
```

How can I ever get `'somehost.com'` through a callback somehow? In other words, `connectTCP` returns an `IConnector` (whatever it does) - how do I correspond this to something tangible in a callback, since no deferreds are used?

Answer (score 3):

Jerub's answer makes sense semantically. After digging through Twisted code, there is a more expedient and direct way of doing specifically what I'm trying to achieve.

In protocol:

```
def connectionMade(self):
    # This is the original connector that connectTCP returned
    connector = self.transport.connector

    # This is the original destination requested
    connector.getDestination()
```

Comment: How would I get this from within a render_GET or render_POST?  The `request` object has a `transport`, but that has no `connector` attribute.  Neither the `Resource` nor the `Site` has `.getDestination()` anywhere near it either.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is, "Record it yourself".

Updating your example:

```
myfactory = MyFactory(connecthost='somehost.com')
reactor.connectTCP(myfactory.connecthost, 80, myfactory)
```

If it's an important piece of information, you should be explicitly passing it around explicitly, in much the same way as you would pass around details about why you connected to a host and what to do once a connection is established.